# define structures in C. Is the book wrong?

Tags: c

This is a sample code Stephen Prata's book : C primer plus, fifth edition. (p965)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct book{
    char title[30];     // **these two lines define char in an array format.**
    char author[30];
    int pagenumber;
} library;


int main(){
    struct book library = {
        "Python",
        "O'reiley",
        200
    };
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s",library.title,library.author,library.pagenumber);
    return 0;
}
```

but the compiler only prints out "O'reiley" and 200, "Python" was missing.

```
$ cpp main.c -o main.ii
$ cc main.ii -o main
$ ./main
O'reiley

200Program exited with status 0
```

However if I change the char from array to pointer format

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct book{
    char *title;     // **these two lines define char in a pointer format.**
    char *author;
    int pagenumber;
} library;


int main(){
    struct book library = {
        "Python",
        "O'reiley",
        200
    };
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s",library.title,library.author,library.pagenumber);
    return 0;
}
```

it gives me the correct result

```
$ cpp main.c -o main.ii
$ cc main.ii -o main
$ ./main
Python
O'reiley
200Program exited with status 0
```

Anyone know why is this？ Is the book wrong?

**EDIT:**
But try this code below, it also gives me an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    struct{
        char name[4];  // it works fine with *name 
        int num;  
        int age;  
        char group;  
        float score;  
    } stu1;
    
    stu1.name = "Tom";
    stu1.num = 12;
    stu1.age = 18;
    stu1.group = 'A';
    stu1.score = 136.5;
    
    printf("%s has student number: %d，he/she is %d，in group %c，grade:%.1f！\n", stu1.name, stu1.num, stu1.age, stu1.group, stu1.score);
    return 0;
}

[Error] assignment to expression with array type
```

Comment: In both cases, your program invokes undefined behavior, because you are using the `%s` format specifier to print an `int`. I suggest you use `%d` instead.

Comment: At least GCC should give a warning about such an error. Be sure to enable compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: Regarding your followup question: The line `stu1.name = "Tom";` is illegal, as the string literal evaluates to a `char*`. You must either set it to `"Tom"` during initialization, as you did in your first piece of code, or you must use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you everyone for answering this.  It seems like using pointer is the safest way.

Comment: @Alex: Note that pointers to string literals are read-only. Therefore, if you want to be able to modify the strings, they will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake there when you specify the type to print for pagenumber:

```
printf("%s\n%s\n%s",library.title,library.author,library.pagenumber);
```

Here the working one:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/cClQP1tcwJIf85zr

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
printf("%s\n%s\n%s",library.title,library.author,library.pagenumber);
                ^^                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're using the wrong format specifier for `library.pagenumber` - you're telling `printf` to write the *sequence of characters* starting at memory address `200`, rather than the string representation of the integer value `200`.  Using the wrong format specifier leads to *undefined behavior* - literally any result is possible, *including the result you expect*.

Changing from using arrays to pointers in the `struct` type didn't fix the problem - it only caused the problem to manifest in a different way that matched what you expected to see.

To print an `int` value, use the `%d` format specifier:

```
printf( "%s\n%s\n%d", library.title, library.author, library.pagenumber );
```

If this is how the code appears in the book, then that's a typo.  Unfortunately, even the best reference books have mistakes.

> stu1.name = "Tom";

This is also a problem - you can't use the `=` operator to assign array contents.  For strings, you'll have to use `strcpy` or `strncpy`, like so:

```
strcpy( stu1.name, "Tom" );
```

or

```
strncpy( stu1.name, "Tom", sizeof stu1.name );
```

For non-character arrays or character arrays that do not store 0-terminated strings, you'd use `memcpy`.

Since `stu1.name` is only 4 elements wide, it can only store strings up to 3 characters long like `"Tom"` - one element needs to be reserved for the string terminator.  If you try to store a longer name with `strcpy`, such as

```
strcpy( stu1.name, "Thomas" );
```

then the `"as"` portion will overwrite anything immediately following `stu1.name`, leading to corrupted data or even a runtime error.  You can use `strncpy` to guard against this:

```
strncpy( stu1.name, "Thomas", sizeof stu1.name );
```

but `stu1.name` won't be properly terminated - you'll have to manually set

```
stu1.name[3] = 0;
```

which leaves you with the string `"Tho"` stored in `stu1.name`.

It "works" when you change `name` from an array to a pointer because what you are storing is the address of the string literal, not the string itself.  This might be easier to understand with a picture.  Assume the following code:

```
char aname[4] = "Tom"; 
char *pname = "Tom";
```

Then what we have is something like this in memory (assuming 32-bit big-endian, addresses are made up out of thin air):

```
            +-----+
0x00004000: | 'T' |
            +-----+
0x00004001: | 'o' |
            +-----+
0x00004002: | 'm' |
            +-----+
0x00004003: |  0  |
            +-----+
              ...
            +-----+
0x7fff4000: | 'T' | aname[0]
            +-----+
0x7fff4001: | 'o' | aname[1]
            +-----+
0x7fff4002: | 'm' | aname[2]
            +-----+
0x7fff4003: |  0  | aname[3]
            +-----+
0x7fff4004: |  00 | pname
            +-----+
0x7fff4008: |  00 | 
            +-----+
0x7fff400c: |  40 |
            +-----+
0x7fff4010: |  00 |
            +-----+
```

The *string literal* `"Tom"` lives in the four bytes starting at address `0x00004000`.  The *array* `aname` lives in the four bytes starting at address `0x7fff4000` and contains the string `"Tom"`.  The *pointer* `pname` lives in the four bytes starting at address `0x7fff4004` and contains the *address* of the string literal `"Tom"`.

Now let's assume you want to change `"Tom"` to `"Thomas"`.  Like I said earlier, you can't use `=` to assign new contents to an array<sup>1</sup>, you would have to use `strncpy`:

```
strncpy( aname, "Thomas", sizeof aname );
aname[3] = 0;
```

However, you can assign a new value to `pname` because what it stores is the *address* of the string, not its contents:

```
pname = "Thomas";
```

After those operations, we have the following:

```
            +-----+
0x00004000: | 'T' |
            +-----+
0x00004001: | 'o' |
            +-----+
0x00004002: | 'm' |
            +-----+
0x00004003: |  0  |
            +-----+
0x00004004: | 'T' |
            +-----+
0x00004005: | 'h' |
            +-----+
0x00004006: | 'o' |
            +-----+
0x00004007: | 'm' |
            +-----+
0x00004008: | 'a' |
            +-----+
0x00004009: | 's' |
            +-----+
0x0000400c: |  0  |
            +-----+

              ...
            +-----+
0x7fff4000: | 'T' | aname[0]
            +-----+
0x7fff4001: | 'h' | aname[1]
            +-----+
0x7fff4002: | 'o' | aname[2]
            +-----+
0x7fff4003: |  0  | aname[3]
            +-----+
0x7fff4004: |  00 | pname
            +-----+
0x7fff4008: |  00 | 
            +-----+
0x7fff400c: |  40 |
            +-----+
0x7fff4010: |  04 |
            +-----+
```

Note that for these kinds of data structures, you typically aren't storing the address of a string literal; usually we *dynamically allocate* a new buffer using `malloc` or `calloc`:

```
 struct{
     char *name;  
     int num;  
     int age;  
     char group;  
     float score;  
 } stu1;

 /**
  * Allocate a dynamic buffer long enough to store the name "Thomas"
  * and assign the pointer to that buffer to `stu1.name`.
  */
 stu1.name = malloc( sizeof *stu1.name * (strlen( "Thomas" ) + 1) );
 if ( stu1.name )
   strcpy( stu1.name, "Thomas" );
```

1. The `=` operator in the declaration is an *initialization*, which is different from assignment.

Answer (score -1):

It does print both `Python` and `O'reiley` but when it reaches the `library.pagenumber` it tries to print it as a string and might fail since it reads the number as a pointer and you might not have access to this address

Answer (score -2):

**in printf you should put %d not %s because pagenumber is an integer. try this code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {

    char title[30]; 
    
    char author[30];

    int pagenumber;
} book;



int main(){

    book library;

        library.title="Python";
        library."O'reiley";
        library.pagenumber=200;
    
    printf("%s\n%s\n%d",library.title,library.author,library.pagenumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer, rather than just posting code.

Comment: The line `library.title="Python";` will not compile. You must either use `strcpy` or set it to `"Python"` during initialization.